# Rolling back a transaction in apache chemistry cmis

Tags: java, transactions, alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I am creating a java application which will connect to alfresco repository and perform some operations. I am using apache chemistry cmis for doing these operations. If i encounter an error during these operations , how will i handle the rollback mechanisms to undo the operation performed using the course of the operation ?

Comment: This is why generally for any serious application, you're probably better creating a custom API, based off Java webscripts for example, that can make each block of operations is atomic. There is a second side effect of using CMIS for lots of operations: each insert creates a transaction, and this goes into the transaction log, and needs to get individually indexed by solr. If you group them, solr will get called once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately each CMIS request has its own transaction, and there is no builtin transaction support across multiple requests!
You need to do the necessary back (ie: through versionning for instance), and then implement your rollback logic manually!